# remove tag [mysqlf]

Tags: discussion, tagging, retag-request

There is this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279921/setting-a-foreign-key-to-an-empty-string) which has the tag
[mysqlf](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysqlf)

As i can't figure out what `mysqlf`can be, in my opinion it is only a typo and should be as such removed.

The linked question is also the **only** one that has that tag

Answer (score 4):

You could just edit that tag to be [mysql] and since it is the only question with that tag, the tag will eventually be deleted by the system automatically.

See [I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it? (duplicate)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71129) for details.